# Is there any possibility to trigger Jenkins build one specific maven module by changes made in that module on specific branch?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm setting up Jenkins jobs, to build each and every module separately. I'm wondering if there is possibility to trigger specific job by changes made in proper maven module, not by any change in branch or it is impossible in current version?

Comment: If you want to build your projects separately, why are they part of a multi-module project?

Comment: Good question, not my idea unfortunately, but product’s owner.

Comment: When you plan to build the modules separately, instead of building the multi-module project as once, think about changing the structure.